# Create a custom object/fields in Salesforce programmatically

Tags: api, salesforce, customization, extend

Here is the how-to for creating custom objects manually in Salesforce.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_qs_customobject.htm

I would like to know can this be done programmatically and if so via which API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Salesforce Metadata API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_intro.htm) for dynamic creation of objects, fields, etc. In particular, there is [createMetadata()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_createMetadata.htm) method.